# Limit spacebar trigger to button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I don't know how to approach this. If I have two divs div id 1 and div id 2. Div id 2 contains a video but is hidden. Div id1 has a button.

If I use the enter key to activate the button div id 1 is hidden and div id 2 is shown with the video paused. However, if I use the spacebar to activate the button, div id 1 is hidden and div id 2 is shown — except the video is playing because the play button is activated when I used the spacebar on the button.

How do I have it so the div id 1 button only is triggered by pressing the spacebar?

HTML

```
            `<div id="container" role="region" aria-label="Introduction to ...">
                <div id="box_01">
                <h2> Intro</h2>
                <p>Intro content</p>
                <button id="button_01" aria-label="Show video">OK</button>
                </div>
                <div id="box_02" aria-hidden="true">
                    <video id="video1" preload="auto" width="480" height="360" poster="" data-able-player>
                      <source type="video/webm" src=""/>
                        <source type="video/mp4" src=""/>
                        <track kind="captions" src=""/>
                    </video>
                </div>
            </div>`
```

Basic CSS

```
.box_02 {
   display:none;
}
```

JQuery

```
<script>
    $('#button_01').on('click', function(e) {
        $('#box_01').hide().attr('aria-hidden','true');
        $('#box_02').fadeIn(300).attr('aria-hidden','false');
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I want to ask if you have tried using `preventDefault` in a document level keypress event handler, but since you haven't posted any code, I won't

Comment: Sorry I should have posted the code but did not because the <button> element uses the spacebar as a trigger natively in the browser so the keycode is not coded. In the script. The code is a simple show/hide on click event. 

Comment: all you're probably going to get by not posting the code you want people to debug is snarky comments and down votes.

Comment: Fair enough. Will post shortly.

Comment: @LaurenceL, so the space bar trigger is just the on click event of the button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if this will help - don't do much with videos, sorry.  This event handler simply just prevents `Enter` and `Spacebar` being handled by the video player element.  You could of course do more than this - but hopefully this is enough to get you some progress

```
$(document).on('keydown', '#video1', function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 32 || e.keyCode == 13) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately still need spacebar to trigger the video play button. However that may work if I apply it to the button.

Comment: $('button#button_01').on('keydown', '#video1', function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 32 || e.keyCode == 13) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});

I think the trick is to prevent the event bubbling on the element you want to use the spacebar on. Just don't know how

Comment: @Laurence L I can't even replicate your problem.  Enter and spacebar do nothing for me - I suspect I'm maybe missing some other elements of your html.  Try removing the test for spacebar (just do `if (e.keyCode == 13) {`)

Comment: Thanks Tibrogargan. I will try that when I get to work tomorrow. Thanks for the tips and the help :-) Have a great evening.